# Recursively subtract two JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, recursion

Let's have an object with some default settings:

```
var defaults = {
    id: '',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    styles: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        background_color: '#000000'
    },
    points: []
}
```

Then, we make our own object, which initially extends the default settings, and makes some changes:

```
var newObject = {
    id: '1', // changed
    x: 10, // changed
    y: 10, // changed
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    styles: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        background_color: '#333333' // changed
    },
    points: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Finally, we need an object, which contains only the values that changed from the default settings, like this:

```
var subtracted = {
    id: '1',
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    styles: {
        background_color: '#333333'
    },
    points: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

The algorithm needs to be recursive, there can be objects within objects. Here is what I have so far:

```
function subtract(a, b) {
    var r = {};

    // For each property of 'b'
    // if it's different than the corresponding property of 'a'
    // place it in 'r'
    for (var key in b) {
        if (typeof(b[key]) == 'object') {
            if (!a[key]) a[key] = {};
            r[key] = subtract(a[key], b[key]);
        } else {
            if (b[key] != a[key]) {
                r[key] = a[key];
            }
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

However, the recursion is not working for arrays, so "points" turns out as an empty object! typeof() detects it as an object and fails to clone its properties, somehow.

https://jsfiddle.net/gd8q1u18/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working. though there is one edit I made in it to make it recursive as well.

```js
var defaults = {
  id: '',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  styles: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    background_color: '#000000'
  },
  points: []
}

var newObject = {
  id: '1', // changed
  x: 10, // changed
  y: 10, // changed
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  styles: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    background_color: '#333333' // changed
  },
  points: [0, 1, 2] // changed
}

var subtracted = {
  id: '1',
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  styles: {
    background_color: '#333333'
  }
}

function isSame(a, b) {
  if (a.length != b.length) return false;
  if (a.filter(function(i) {
      return a.indexOf(i) < 0;
    }).length > 0)
    return false;
  if (b.filter(function(i) {
      return a.indexOf(i) < 0;
    }).length > 0)
    return false;
  return true;
};

function subtract(a, b) {
  var r = {};

  // For each property of 'b'
  // if it's different than the corresponding property of 'a'
  // place it in 'r'
  for (var key in b) {
    if (Array.isArray(b[key])) {
      if (!a[key]) a[key] = [];
      if (!isSame(a[key], b[key]))
        r[key] = a[key];
    } else if (typeof(b[key]) == 'object') {
      if (!a[key]) a[key] = {};
      r[key] = subtract(a[key], b[key]);
    } else {
      if (b[key] != a[key]) {
        r[key] = a[key];
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}

console.log(subtract(newObject, defaults));
```

Comment: Yes, sure! The website wouldn't allow me to accept it right away. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if there is an array in the object :/ https://jsfiddle.net/gd8q1u18/1/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: another approach a little bit more toward recursion. It runs through modifications so newObject can disregard some fields. It works with primitives too.

```js
const equalArrays = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((element, index) => element === arr2[index])
// notice that equalArrays matters the order of the arrays' elements.
// If order doesn't matter, consider sorting both arrays first

const isObject = (obj) => obj instanceof Object && !(obj instanceof Array)
// notice that arrays are instance of Objects too
// an unwary consumer might mix arrays and objects with unpredictable results

const isArray = (arr) => arr instanceof Array

const getDifferences = (original, modified) => {
  const areArrays = isArray(original) && isArray(modified)
  const areObjects = isObject(original) && isObject(modified)
  if (areObjects) {
    let result = {}
    for (const key of Object.keys(modified)) {
      const diff = getDifferences(original[key], modified[key])
      if (diff) result[key] = diff
    }
    return !!Object.keys(result).length && result
  }
  else if (areArrays && !equalArrays(original, modified)) return modified
  else if (original !== modified) return modified
}
// notice that some variables and functions are there for readability and might be inlined

let defaults = {
  id: '',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  styles: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    background_color: '#000000'
  },
  points: []
}

let newObject = {
  id: '1', // changed
  x: 10, // changed
  y: 10, // changed
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  styles: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    background_color: '#333333' // changed
  },
  points: [0, 1, 2] // changed
}

console.log(getDifferences(defaults, newObject))
```

I would take into account that some unwary consumer might mix arrays and objects.

```js
const equalArrays = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((element, index) => element === arr2[index])
// notice that equalArrays matters the order of the arrays' elements.
// If order doesn't matter, consider sorting both arrays first

const isObject = (obj) => obj instanceof Object && !(obj instanceof Array)
// notice that arrays are instance of Objects too
// an unwary consumer might mix arrays and objects with unpredictable results

const isArray = (arr) => arr instanceof Array

const getDifferences = (obj1, obj2) => {
  let obj3 = {}
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj1)) {
    const val1 = obj1[key]
    const val2 = obj2[key]
    const areArrays = isArray(val1) && isArray(val2)
    const areObjects = isObject(val1) && isObject(val2)
    if (areObjects) {
      const diff = getDifferences(val1, val2)
      if (diff) obj3[key] = diff
    }
    else if (areArrays && !equalArrays(val1, val2)) obj3[key] = val2
    else if (val1 !== val2) obj3[key] = val2
  }
  return !!Object.keys(obj3).length && obj3
}
// notice that some variables and functions are there for readability and might be inlined

let defaults = {
  id: '',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  styles: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    background_color: '#000000'
  },
  points: []
}

let newObject = {
  id: '1', // changed
  x: 10, // changed
  y: 10, // changed
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  styles: {
    color: '#ffffff',
    background_color: '#333333' // changed
  },
  points: [0, 1, 2] // changed
}

console.log(getDifferences(defaults, newObject))
```